# How to retain table structure when it is read from a PDF and stored in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib

I used the read_pdf from tabula to read the table present in a PDF by specifying the area parameters. I wish to retain the table structure as is (including the lines in between the columns and rows (if applicable)). I read that matplotlib can be used to do, but when I try to put the read table into a CSV, the table structure vanishes and there are only spaces between rows of column. 
My code-

```
from tabula import read_pdf
import csv
path = "---"
df = read_pdf(path, stream=True , encoding="utf-8", guess = False, nospreadsheet = True, area = (112.37, 35.34, 153.36, 212.43))
print(df)
df.to_csv("path to destination csv file")

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False) 
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)

ax.table(cellText=df.values, colLabels=df.columns, loc='center')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

When I look into the content of the destination csv file, the lines between columns are not retained. 
For example, in the below given PDF, i wish to read data from the table and put it into  a csv file by retaining the lines between columns, whereas my code doesn't retain the lines.

[image: [1]]

whereas i want my code to produce a csv file that bifurcates or draws lines between the columns like this-

[image: required table in csv]

The pdf included here is sample. My original pdf is displaying the following output when i used matplotlib. [image], 
whereas i want it to look like this-> (only the part inside the black lines with the bifurcation)[image]

Comment: the [tag:tablua] does not apply here - you are not using a Java GUI to convert pdf. same for [tag:matplotlib] - @Scotty1 removed the [tag:csv] as well - no idea why - this is about a (misconcepted) csv.

Comment: @PatrickArtner, I have a pdf, that I converted into a text file, after which, i used the original pdf to locate the place of the table and pull back only the table content along with the structure and store it into a csv. Matplotlib can be used to show up such table structures in a neat, tabular way right?Used these sources- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45457054/tabula-extract-tables-by-area-coordinates,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32137396/how-do-i-plot-only-a-table-in-matplotlib

Comment: @PatrickArtner I also removed CSV, since the problem is, in my opinion, not directly related to csv. developer asks for a table style with lines between the columns (or as I'd recommend: a list of values in the second column to be able to work with the comma separated format), which is not specific to CSV, nor any other common table style. So I thought adding the tag `csv` because of one single line of code, which is not even the "core" of the question, was not justified.

Comment: @Scotty1- sure. Understood

Comment: @developer the tags guide SO users to your question. Ask yourself: what part of your questions would a "matplotlib"-experienced user interest - you never show what you did with mathplotlib so there is no  "code to improve" - hence mathplotlib should not be tagged imho - you also used windows or linux as system .. you would not want to tag windows or linux .. it has nothing to do with the content of your question

Comment: @PatrickArtner, I have edited my code to show the matplotlib part where i tried to use it to generate a table from the dataframe i had.

Comment: Matplotlib tables do have lines in between rows, so I'm a bit confused to what the question is. Can you show a screenshot of the outcome of your code and use it to explain what is different to the desired outcome?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest , I have edited my question to show the output i am getting and the output i desire to get

Comment: Neither dataframes, nor matplotlib tables know the concept of "column-spanning". This would need to be done manually.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Okay thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `csv`-format (**c**[haracter/omma]  **s**eparated **v**alues) are values seperated by (the same) seperator character. `csv` is text-based - there are no "lines" in it.

There are unicode characters that can be used to "form lines":

> ```
>     U+2500    ─   e2 94 80    &#9472; ─   BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT HORIZONTAL
>     U+2501    ━   e2 94 81    &#9473; ━   BOX DRAWINGS HEAVY HORIZONTAL
>     U+2502    │   e2 94 82    &#9474; │   BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT VERTICAL
>     U+2503    ┃   e2 94 83    &#9475; ┃   BOX DRAWINGS HEAVY VERTICAL
> ... snipp ...
>     U+250C    ┌   e2 94 8c    &#9484; ┌   BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT DOWN AND RIGHT
>     U+250D    ┍   e2 94 8d    &#9485; ┍   BOX DRAWINGS DOWN LIGHT AND RIGHT HEAVY
>     U+250E    ┎   e2 94 8e    &#9486; ┎   BOX DRAWINGS DOWN HEAVY AND RIGHT LIGHT
> ... snipp ...
>     U+2533    ┳   e2 94 b3    &#9523; ┳   BOX DRAWINGS HEAVY DOWN AND HORIZONTAL
>     U+2534    ┴   e2 94 b4    &#9524; ┴   BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT UP AND HORIZONTAL
>     U+2535    ┵   e2 94 b5    &#9525; ┵   BOX DRAWINGS LEFT HEAVY AND RIGHT UP LIGHT
> ... snipp ...
>     U+2548    ╈   e2 95 88    &#9544; ╈   BOX DRAWINGS UP LIGHT AND DOWN HORIZONTAL HEAVY
>     U+2549    ╉   e2 95 89    &#9545; ╉   BOX DRAWINGS RIGHT LIGHT AND LEFT VERTICAL HEAVY
>     U+254A    ╊   e2 95 8a    &#9546; ╊   BOX DRAWINGS LEFT LIGHT AND RIGHT VERTICAL HEAVY
>     U+254B    ╋   e2 95 8b    &#9547; ╋   BOX DRAWINGS HEAVY VERTICAL AND HORIZONTAL
> ```
>
> [source](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl)

But you would have to "typeset" each line piece on its own to mimic a table in unicode:

```
┍━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━┓
┃   tata         ┃   ta    ┃    fo   ┃  ka     ┃
┝━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╈━━━━━━━━╈━━━━━━━━╈━━━━━━━━┧
┃   1234         ┃   45    ┃   79    ┃  45     ┃
┝━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╈━━━━━━━━╈━━━━━━━━╈━━━━━━━━┧
┃   1234         ┃   45    ┃   79    ┃  45     ┃
┕━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━┛
```

However this is no csv - it is more like human readable [ascii-art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art).
The corresponding csv would be:

```
tata,ta,fo,ka
1234,45,79,45
1234,45,79,45
```

(if using `,` as seperator char - replace with char you like better: `[" ","|",";",\t]` )

---

*Disclaimer:*

I am purposefully bad at ascii-art and choose not to match exactly corresponding unicode lines (LIGHT, HEAVY) to get my point across. This is on purpose - call me lazy.

Comment: Thank you. is there a way by which i could retain the table structure if not for csv?

Answer (score 0):

Seperate answer - this code formats a "well-defined" csv

```
tata,ta,for,kattatom
1234,45,79,45
1234,45,79,45
```

into a "utf8-art":

```
┌────┬──┬───┬────────┐
│tata│ta│for│kattatom│
├────┼──┼───┼────────┤
│1234│45│79 │45      │
├────┼──┼───┼────────┤
│1234│45│79 │45      │
└────┴──┴───┴────────┘
```

The utf8-art is appended to the file `output.txt`.

---

```
import csv 

def create_table(file_name):
    """Takes a file_name to a csv. Produces utf8-art of the data. 
    Missing columns will be assumed to miss at end and replaced 
    by empty columns."""
    # mostly untested code - works for the 2 examples mentioned here
    with open(file_name,"r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f) 
        w = get_widths(reader)
        row_count = w["last"] 
        del w["last"]
        f.seek(0)
        return create_table_string(reader, w, row_count)

def get_widths(csv_reader):
    widths = {}
    row_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if row: # ignore empties
            row_count += 1
            for idx,data in enumerate(row):
                widths[idx] = max(widths.get(idx,0),len(data))

    widths["last"] = row_count
    return widths

# supply other set of lines if you like
deco = {k:v for k,v in zip("hv012345678","─│┌┬┐├┼┤└┴┘")} 


def base_row(widths, row, max_key, _v, _h, _l, _m, _r):
    decoration = []
    text_data = []

    decoration.append(_l + _h*widths[0])
    for i in range(1,max_key):
        decoration.append(_m + _h*widths[i])
    decoration.append(_m + _h*widths[max_key] + _r)

    if row:
        for i,data in enumerate(row): 
            text_data.append(_v + "{:<{}}".format(data, widths[i]))

        for empty in range(i+1,max_key+1):
            text_data.append(_v + " "*widths[empty])
        text_data[-1]+=_v

    return [decoration, text_data]

def get_first_row(widths,row):
    return base_row(widths, row, max(widths.keys()), deco["v"], deco["h"], 
                    deco["0"], deco["1"], deco["2"])

def get_middle_row(widths,row):
    return base_row(widths, row, max(widths.keys()),  deco["v"], deco["h"],
                    deco["3"], deco["4"], deco["5"])

def get_last_row(widths):
    decoration, _ = base_row(widths, [], max(widths.keys()), deco["v"], 
                             deco["h"], deco["6"], deco["7"], deco["8"])

    return [decoration]


def create_table_string(reader, widths, row_count): 
    output = []
    r = 0 
    for row in reader:
        if row:
            r += 1
            if r==1:
                output.extend(get_first_row(widths, row))
            else:
                output.extend(get_middle_row(widths, row))

    output.extend( get_last_row(widths))
    return output
```

Usage:

```
#create sample csv
with open("data.csv","w") as f:
    f.write("""tata,ta,for,kattatom
1234,45,79,45
1234,45,79,45""")

# open outputfile for append
with open("output.txt", "a", encoding="UTF8") as output:
    output.write("\n" + "-" * 40 + "\n\n")

    # get utf8 art
    for line in create_table("data.csv"):
        output.write(''.join(line)+"\n")
```

Input csv:

```
tata,ta,for,kattatom
1234,45,79,45
1234,45,79,45
```

then:

```
tata,ta,for,kattatom
1234,45,79,45,8,0
1234,45,79,45
```

Output:

```
┌────┬──┬───┬────────┐
│tata│ta│for│kattatom│
├────┼──┼───┼────────┤
│1234│45│79 │45      │
├────┼──┼───┼────────┤
│1234│45│79 │45      │
└────┴──┴───┴────────┘

----------------------------------------

┌────┬──┬───┬────────┬─┬─┐
│tata│ta│for│kattatom│ │ │
├────┼──┼───┼────────┼─┼─┤
│1234│45│79 │45      │8│0│
├────┼──┼───┼────────┼─┼─┤
│1234│45│79 │45      │ │ │
└────┴──┴───┴────────┴─┴─┘
```