# Can tabula lead with merge columns?

Tags: python, pandas, tabula

Recently I've working in table extraction, specifically with *stream* tables. An in [this](https://github.com/camelot-dev/camelot/wiki/Comparison-with-other-PDF-Table-Extraction-libraries-and-tools) post I saw that tabula achieves very well this kind of extraction.
For example when compares `tabula` vs `camelot` in "[budget.pdf](https://github.com/atlanhq/camelot/blob/master/docs/benchmark/stream/budget/budget.pdf)", in the extraction Tabula combines the last two columns. Using `.split(' ', expand = True)` can be fixed and then use `combine`, `join` or `merge` make the original pdf table.

I noticed that when the gap between the columns is so close they would be merged in one. In the taks that I'm trying to achieve that is very common. I don't know how well might be my solution because in some examples that I work on in the middle of the dataframe the columns are merged and I have to sort the columns of the whole dataframe.

I would like to know if Tabula has a hyperparameter tuning to deal with that, like `PDFMiner` in which you can manage distances between values...

Answer (score 0):

maintainer of Tabula here.

You can try specifying the horizontal coordinates of the column boundaries. This parameter is exposed in `tabula-py` in the `columns=` keyword argument of the `read_pdf` method.

Comment: If I don't know the exactly location of the columns, ```tabula-py``` has an option to plot the pdf page as: ```camelot.plot(tables[0], kind='grid').show()``` ?

Comment: You can find out the position of elements on the page with the Measure tool in Acrobat Reader. Here's more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45457054/tabula-extract-tables-by-area-coordinates/45516398#45516398