# Tabula-py doesn't recognise columns correct

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, tabula

I am trying to recognise pdf document using tabula. I use this code:

```
df = tabula.read_pdf(io.BytesIO(content), pages=12,pandas_options={'header': None}, multiple_tables = True,columns=(78.39, 226.97, 280.97,370.04,461.02,550.06))
```

However, after recognition, the first two columns are one single column. I tried to change columns
coordinates, but it didn't help.

Also, I tried to use guess=False, and it doesn't help too.

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this issue?
Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Open PDF with SumatraPDF reader.
Press ‘m’ to activate measurement display on top left.
Then position cursor over top left and bottom right of table to get coordinates as below:

[image]

Bottom right:

[image]

4. Run command :

`java -jar tabula-1.0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar -p 2 -a 164,20,390,771 "myPdf.pdf" -o outfile.csv`

Note:
a)  option ‘p’ gives page number

b)  option ‘a’ has area of table (top,left,bottom,right) – coordinates got from SumatraPDF reader.

c)  "[DEMO USE ONLY] Create_Opp_1822018_111526_AM - signed.pdf" is pdf to extract from

d)  Option ‘o’ gives filename to save to. Delete this file if existing before running tabula command.

This will create csv